# How to do an async fetch before initial render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, next.js, headless-cms

I'm currently making use of the Wordpress API using Next.js on the front end. I want to fetch my navigation/menu data and have it prerendered. I've tried but only an empty `<nav> </nav>` element is rendered when I check the source-code. Is there a simple solution to this?

Here is my Nav component:

```
import { Config } from "../config";
import Link from "next/link";
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";

    export default function MainNav() {
      const links = useFetch(`${Config.apiUrl}/wp-json/menus/v1/menus/main-nav`);
    
      return (
        <nav>
          {!!links &&
            links.map((link) => (
              <Link href="/">
                <a>{link.title}</a>
              </Link>
            ))}
        </nav>
      );
    }
```

And my custom `useFetch.js` hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useFetch(url) {
  const [links, setLinks] = useState();

  //   Must use useEffect in non-page component

  useEffect(async () => {
    let res = await fetch(url);
    res = await res.json();
    setLinks(res.items);
  }, []);

  return links;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all useEffect is not async at all, even if you define `async` inside the `useEffect` callback function, the proper way to do this, is to set up separate state - `useState(false)` for spinner or include that into exisiting one, which will control the spinner, since you are fetching the data via REST, basically the full example should look like this:

`useFetch.js` hook:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useFetch(url) {
  const [{ links, isLoading }, setLinks] = useState({ links: [], isLoading: true });

  //   Must use useEffect in non-page component

  useEffect(() => {
    (async funtion() {
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const { items } = await res.json();
      setLinks({ links: items, isLoading: false });
    })()
   
  }, []);

  return [isLoading, links];
}
```

`Nav.js` component:

```js
import { Config } from "../config";
import Link from "next/link";
import useFetch from "../hooks/useFetch";

    export default function MainNav() {
      const [links, isLoading] = useFetch(`${Config.apiUrl}/wp-json/menus/v1/menus/main-nav`);

      if(isLoading) {
        return <Spinner/>
      }
    
      return (
        <nav>
          {!!links && !isLoading &&
            links.map((link) => (
              <Link href="/">
                <a>{link.title}</a>
              </Link>
            ))}
        </nav>
      );
    }
```

Comment: Also I will include an article which explains how we can fetch the data with help of `async` in `useEffect` hook:
https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer as I wasn't aware that useEffect nullified async. However, this doesn't help me with server-side rendering.

Comment: Okay, for SSR solution you gonna need to have a request on the Node.js side, to be exact:
1. Before rendering everything, make a request to the Headless CMS ( Node.js and attach stuff to your final markup, just a HTML string ).
2. After receiveing the response, create static HTML and then send it to the UI
3. Make ReactDOM hydrate pre-rendered makrup
4. That's all, unfortunatelly, this is quite a lot of work to do that for 1 static menu, and to be honest and don't really know if you are able to tinker Next.js SSR renderer and do custom stuff on that side

Comment: My solution was a lot simpler. I just used getStaticProps() on the page and then passed it down to the component through component composition. The downside is that the components need to be agnostic about their children. Considering it's not a massive project, it seems to be the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, I fetched the links data on the page that the component was nested onto and then fed the data down using component composition. The problem is that I have to nest them all on the page directly. If someone has a more elegant solution, please let me know :)

The page `index.js`:

```
import PostIndex from "../components/PostIndex";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import MainNav from "../components/MainNav";

import { Config } from "../config";

export default function Home(props) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Header>
        <MainNav links={props.links} />
      </Header>
      <h2>Home Page</h2>
      <PostIndex limit={3} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const [data1, data2] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(`${Config.apiUrl}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=3`),
    fetch(`${Config.apiUrl}/wp-json/menus/v1/menus/main-nav`),
  ]);
  const posts = await data1.json();
  const links = await data2.json();
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
      links,
    },
  };
}
```

The `Layout.js` component:

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return <div>{children}</div>;
}
```

The `Header.js` component:

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Header({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Link href="/">
        <a>
          <h1>Wordpress Blog</h1>
        </a>
      </Link>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the `MainNev.js` component:

```
import { Config } from "../config";
import Link from "next/link";

export default function MainNav({ links }) {
  return (
    <nav>
      {!!links &&
        links.items.map((item) => (
          <Link href="/">
            <a>{item.title}</a>
          </Link>
        ))}
    </nav>
  );
}
```